# Executing SQL Function using toad

Tags: sql, oracle, function, toad

I am very new to DB. I am java developer and nothing to do with SQL Functions.
But now I am in a situation where I need to check whether an sql function is getting executed properly on db or not

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RATELIMIT_OWN.Get_Logs ( p_yyyymm VARCHAR2, p_numec NUMBER )
RETURN LOG_RECORD_TABLE PIPELINED IS

TYPE        ref0 IS REF CURSOR;
cur0        ref0;

out_rec     LOG_RECORD := log_record(NULL,NULL,NULL);

BEGIN

OPEN cur0 FOR
  'SELECT eventid, errormsg, create_date from logs partition (LOGS_P' || p_yyyymm || ') where numec=:1'
USING p_numec;

  LOOP
   FETCH cur0 INTO out_rec.eventid, out_rec.msg, out_rec.create_date;
   EXIT WHEN cur0%NOTFOUND;
   PIPE ROW(out_rec);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur0;

RETURN;
END Get_Logs;
/
```

How to execute this sql function in toad. I want to see the results like normal Select query output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOE EXECUTING THE FUNCTION    
SELECT RATELIMIT_OWN.Get_Logs(....,...) FROM DUAL ;

AND
ORA-00904:  MEAN COLUMN NAME IS NOT VALID PLSS CHECK THE COLUMN NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

To check a table valued function please try:

```
select * FROM table(RATELIMIT_OWN.Get_Logs('a', 1));
```

Comment: I am getting below error 

 select * FROM table(RATELIMIT_OWN.Get_Logs('a', 1))
                    *
 Error at line 1
 ORA-02149: Specified partition does not exist
 ORA-06512: at "RATELIMIT_OWN.GET_LOGS", line 11

Comment: Please check/confirm the parameters supplied to the function. i.e. 'a' and 1.

Comment: Replace the values 'a' and 1 with your parameters in the statement "select * FROM table(RATELIMIT_OWN.Get_Logs('a', 1));".

Comment: What's the output of select * from dba_tab_partitions where table_name = 'LOGS' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 select  RATELIMIT_OWN.Get_Logs(...) from dual;
```

Comment: Error:

select  RATELIMIT_OWN.Get_Logs('a',1) from dual
*
Error at line 0
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: I am complete newbie to SQL. I don't know what's cursor cur0!

Let me know what statement to execute, I will do and post back

Comment: Is this query: `'SELECT eventid, errormsg, create_date from logs partition (LOGS_P' || p_yyyymm || ') '` works? You have to replace  `p_yyyymm` with your parameter for example `'a'`.

Comment: With you parameter 'a' , query looks like: `SELECT eventid, errormsg, create_date from logs partition (LOGS_Pa)` . Try run it.